# Unix fork() system call what runs when?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

```
void child(int pid){
    printf("Child PID:%d\n",pid);
    exit(0);    
}
void parent(int pid){
    printf("Parent PID:%d\n",pid);
    exit(0);
}

void init(){
    printf("Init\n");//runs before the fork
}


int main(){

    init();//only runs for parent i.e. runs once
    printf("pre fork()");// but this runs for both i.e. runs twice
    //why???

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        child(pid); //run child process
    }else{
        parent(pid);//run parent process
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Init
pre fork()Parrent PID:4788
pre fork()Child PID:0
```

I have a process in a Unix OS (Ubuntu in my case). I can't for the life of me understand how this works. I know the `fork()` function splits my programs in two processes but from where? Does it create a new process and run the whole main function again, and if so why did the `init()` only run once and the `printf()` twice?

Why does the `printf("pre fork()");` run twice and the `init()` function only once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printf anomaly after "fork()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)

Comment: @NateEldredge the answer from 9 year ago that i accepted answered my question :P
But thx, i guess :P

Comment: Sorry for the noise, I was just trying to mark some duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's only one process until the fork. That is, that path is executed only once. After the fork there are 2 processes so the code following that system call is executed by both processes. What you ignore is that both terminate and both will call `exit`.

**In your code you're not flushing `stdio`**. So both processes do that (exit flushes stdio buffers) - that's why you're seeing that output.

Try this:

```
printf("pre fork()\n");
                  ^^ should flush stdout
```

Or maybe

```
printf("pre fork()\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Wow, this is so subtle!  +1 from me!

Comment: Simply putting a newline in does not necessarily flush the buffer.  Run the code with stdout redirected to a regular file and you will see exactly the same behavior.  stdout is *not* line buffered by default unless it is a tty.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's completely right. And even if the destination is a tty, the standard doesn't guarantee `\n` will trigger a flush.