# fork() command in c -- what is the output to this simple piece of code?

Tags: c++, c, process, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix fork() system call what runs when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863447/unix-fork-system-call-what-runs-when)

I looked on Wikipedia, and the article said, "The purpose of fork() system call is to create a new process, which becomes the child process of caller, after which both, the parent and child processes, **will execute the code following the fork() system call**. Hence, it is important to distinguish between parent and child process. This can be done by testing the return value of fork() system call."

In that case, what does this code execute:

```
printf("This is a fork!");
fork();
```

Given the description, it looks like it will say "This is a fork!" just once, since nothing lies AFTER the fork() statement. However, when I tested this out on a linux box, it printed "This is a fork!" twice. So which is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output of printf is buffered; both child processes got a copy of the buffer; the buffer was flushed twice when each child process exited.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` has buffered its output for later display. That later happens to come after the `fork`, so you see it twice.

Replace your code fragment with:

```
printf("...");
fflush(stdout);
fork();
```