# How to solve this fork() example in c,

Tags: c, fork

I am supposed to work out this code to tell the output for my homework. Could somebody help me out? I'm not looking for the answer but, step by step instructions of how to understand this.

```
 int main() 
 { 
     int pid; 
     int val = 5; 

     pid = fork(); 

     if (pid == 0) val += 3; 

     if (val == 5) val++; 

     printf(“val=%d\n”, val); 
     exit(0); 
 }
```

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried to run it yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
pid = fork(); 
if (pid == 0) val += 3; 
if (val == 5) val++; 
printf(“val=%d\n”, val);
```

Case 1: After `fork()` , parent gets scheduled before the child , and complete's `printf()` call successfully

```
    val = 6;         //printed by parent
    val = 8;         //printed by child
```

Case 2: After `fork()` , parent gets scheduled before the child , and complete's printf() call successfully

```
    val = 8;         //printed by child
    val = 6;         //printed by parent
```

-- Problem with `printf()` and `fork()` --

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Before forking");
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
        printf("child printing");
    else
        printf("parent printing");
}
```

The output is

```
term# ./a.out 
Before forkingparent printingBefore forkingchild printing
```

The problem above is clear that , the statement "Before forking" , is printed twice , where it should have printed only once.

The solution is

1. Use `'\n'` , to buffer each line after every `printf()` call.
2. As rightly advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork) call `fflush(0)` , to empty all I/O buffers before forking.

Comment: printf() is not atomic , in between the function call , the process can be preempted , happened to me once

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , do have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork

Comment: That wouldn't have any relevance here. `val` is always known in this program.

Comment: If stdout is line buffered (which it usually is), then I don't think that can happen here, as all the newline characters are in the "correct" place.

Comment: The `printf()` call is line-buffered, so it will call `write()` once, and the underlying `write()` will be atomic.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , yes as long as '\n' is present , it is line buffered and there will be no problems , but just so without '\n' , i thought it was a case to consider

Comment: It'd still be fine without the `\n` (both would just appear on the same line).

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks for the info , will look a little more closely at printf()

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , i have edited my answer , to clarify my last comment

Comment: I'm not sure any of what you've just added is relevant, given that that isn't what the OP's code does.

Comment: @BarathBushan: again, this cannot fail. `printf` makes one system call from each process. Since each process only writes one line, there is no issue at all.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth just making the OP aware of the problem between printf() and fork() , and suggesting proper solutions to handle them...

Answer (score 1):

The code will print one of the three following options:

```
val=6
```

```
val=8
val=6
```

```
val=6
val=8
```

It depends on which `write()` syscall completes first: child or parent, and whether the child process is successfully created (it might fail).

Comment: Can you explain why you think `val=5` will get printed ? I understand the other 2 possibilites though which I right now think are the only valid outputs.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - yes there cannot be a `val = 5`, but why would there be a case where the parent process prints nothing ?

Comment: @Tuxdude: Because the fork may fail.

Comment: Oh, never really thought about that case, good catch - and yeah `val=6` for that case makes sens :)