# Using Forks with waitpid

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

Are there 3 child processes and 1 parent process?
What does the two different waitpid do, and why are there two of them?

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    int status, counter = 4;
    while(counter > 0)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid)
        {
            counter /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", counter); /* (1) */
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pid)
    {
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        counter += WEXITSTATUS(status);
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        counter += WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf(";%d", counter); /* (2) */
    }
    return counter;
}
```

the second printf after the waitpid prints 3, 5, 6, 34, 52, 61 (excluding the semicolon).
Im not sure how there are two digits printing. I know the second digit is probably coming from the printf in the while loop.

Comment: Put a prefix before the `printf` in the while loop, so you can tell where it starts.

Comment: Note that some children will also fork.

Comment: @egur how so? `fork()` is only called in a piece of code that requires `counter > 0` after the fork, the child (with `pid == 0`) breaks out of the loop that performs the `fork()`.

Comment: My mistake, long day. didn't see the break;

Comment: @NeilBharatPatel when I run your code, my output is `412;5`.  Notice that my output order (4, 1, 2) is not what you would expect -- this is normal though, you aren't controlling the synchronization of your children. You will get a more accurate (time-wise) view of the output if you flush the output after each print (fflush, or just include \n at the end) but that might not be enough... true synchronization (waiting on a mutex that governs access to the output resource) would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 3 child processes and 1 parent. Children return 4, 2, 1.

To collect all statuses, you could use a while loop:

```
if(pid)
{
  while (waitpid(-1, &status, 0) != -1) /* ignoring signals, errors */
    counter += WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
return counter;
```

Parent returns 7 in this case.

If you use only two `waitpid()` calls then they may return any pair from `{4,2,1}` set e.g., `{4,1}` or `{2,1}` so parent prints `;5` and `;3` correspondingly.

Due to stdio buffering and `fork()` interaction, the output may multiply. See [printf anomaly after “fork()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)

Either `fflush()` before `fork()` or use `write/_exit` in children instead.