# Is the fork on mac (OSX-10.9.2) with the default compiler(gcc-4.2) any different from normal fork?

Tags: c, unix, printf, fork

I'm executing this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    pid_t pid;
    pid = getpid();
    printf("my pid is %d", pid);
    fork();
    pid = getpid();
    if(pid < 0) {
            printf("error creating child process");
            exit(1);
    }
    if(pid > 0) {
            printf("\n my child's pid is %d \n", pid);
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("hello from child process, im still running");
    return 0;
```

}

I expect the result to be :

```
my pid is 5830
 my child's pid is 5831
hello from child process, i'm still running
```

But I get these results :

```
my pid is 5830
 my child's pid is 5830 
my pid is 5830
 my child's pid is 5831
```

What am i doing wrong? Well, as the title suggests, 
i'm running this on my mac - 10.9.2 and

```
    gcc --version returns :    

    i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM  build 2336.11.00)
    Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
    There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I tried getting the pid as the return value of the fork() call, it doesn't help either

Comment: This code won't work. You need to be checking the return value of `fork`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did that, it's not helping...

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf anomaly after "fork()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `printf` call has no newline at the end of the string. The write is getting buffered and when the `fork` occurs you end up with two processes that each have a copy of the buffer. When the parent and child next call `printf` and include a newline, the buffers get flushed - hence the duplication. Add a newline to the end of the string to fix the duplication.

You also need to be inspecting the return value of `fork` (not `getpid`) to determine whether you're in the parent or child. `getpid` in the child will return the actual pid, not 0. Currently both the parent and the child think they're the parent.

Comment: It doesn't help, I still get the same error... Did you run it and check?

Comment: The above program works, after I removed the getpid(), and the printf before the fork().