# Understanding unix fork

Tags: unix, process, fork

Can anyone explain why the line containing "here" is executed 5 times and how exactly the program runs because I don't seem to understand how I get this output

Output:

```
12958: 0 here
12959: 0
12958: 0 here
12958: 1 here
12960: 1
12958: 0 here
12958: 1 here
```

Code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("%d: %d here\n", getpid(), i);
        if(fork()==0){
            printf("%d: %d\n", getpid(), i);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        wait(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: because I'm running windows on my computer I used this website [link](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) to check the code, could that be a problem?

Comment: Running it using that website actually runs it on a *nix machine.

Comment: yes I know that, but I thought it's worth mentioning that it's not local

Comment: Like ooga said it's something to do with output buffers. Here is a more detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork creates an almost identical process, including the output buffers. If these are not flushed before the `fork`, both processes can end up printing the contents. Try putting a `fflush(stdout);` after the parent's `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to get the output you mentioned. As I tested your code my output was the following

11194: 0 here

11194: 1 here

11195: 0

11196: 1

Maybe you should recompile it and try again?

Comment: What system did you run this on?

Comment: I see. It's different on different systems, though, depending on how output buffering works.