# Forking a process- execution before the system call (execution point)

Tags: c, fork

"When we call fork() on a process and its child is created, it is said that the point of execution starts from the point next to the fork() call in both the processes. But when I checked,

```
main() {
    printf("hello");
    val =fork();
    if(val==0){
        printf("child");
    }
    if(val>0){
        printf("parent");
    }
}
```

This program printed hello also twice. I am a little confused. Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf anomaly after "fork()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)

Comment: amongst other problems with the code, this line: val =fork(); should be PID_t val =fork(); and have the #include for the definition of PID_t

Comment: this second print of hello is because the output is buffered and the buffer had not been emptied, by either a '\n' at the end of the hello string or by the initial printf being followed by fflush(stdout);  So the hello is still in the output buffer

Answer (score 2):

When you do `printf("hello");`, the output is line buffered for `STDOUT` which is not flushed. Now when the buffer still containing data, `fork()` call makes both parent and child process inherit data present in the buffer making it print twice.

Ideally you should be flushing the standard output as below:

```
printf("hello");
fflush(stdout);
fork();
```

Comment: Or adding a `\n` at the end of the string.