# c: how does function waitpid work?

Tags: c

In studying CSAPP, I encounter the practice: list all of the possible output sequences for the following program:

```
int main()
{
        if(Fork()==0)   {
                printf("a");
        }
        else {
                printf("b");
                waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
        }
        printf("c");
        exit(0);
}
```

> the answer is :acbc  abcc   bcac bacc;

Why is `bcac` correct?   The function `waitpid()` suspends execution of the calling process until the child process in its wait set terminates. So the parent can't not print `c`, until the child process terminate, which means the child prints both `a` and `c`.
   I'm really confused about it.  I don't know why `bcac` is correct. The parent process should hold or suspend until child terminates.

Comment: are you sure its `Fork()`?

Comment: Might be due to buffering. Output to `stdout` (which is what `printf` is using) is *line buffered* by default. Output isn't flushed until the buffer is full (will not happen here), there is a newline printed (does not happen here), there's an explicit `fflush` call (does not happen here), or the process exits and the out is flushed.

Comment: Probably another duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2530663/694576

Comment: Fork() :  pid_t Fork(void)
{
        pit_t pid;

        if((pid = fork()) < 0)
                unix_error("Fork error");
        return pid;
}

Comment: The C library provides `pid_t fork(void)`. Please note the case.

Comment: @alk See: https://github.com/mofaph/csapp/blob/master/code/src/csapp.c

Comment: I found the exercise you are refering to here: http://square.seoultech.ac.kr/~icom/newsysprog/textbook/ch8.pdf . This is obviously an error in the script. You are correct, `bcac` is not a valid outcome.

Comment: I thought there was a possibility that some POSIX system would return EINTR. seeing the csapp.c, it is not a possibility any more and I too say that `bcac` is not valid

Comment: You should define Fork in your code example, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim Pileborg suggests, this is a flushing output problem.
Just use the following:

```
int main()
{
    if(Fork()==0)
    {
        printf("a\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("b\n");
        waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
    }
    printf("c\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

'\n' characters should automatically flush stdout or stderr.
You can also use fflush(stdout);

Comment: I tend to disagree, this can not be a buffering issue since exit() will flush stdout implicitly.

Comment: @Ctx Is that completely sure the parent is awaken only after stdout is flushed?

Comment: Yes, it is, with standard buffering you will _always_ get `acbc` with the OP's code. Assuming no buffering, additionally `abcc` and `bacc` are possible. `bcac` never is.