# execl & printf - order

Tags: c, execl

I have a small problem with this:

```
{
  printf ("abc");
  execl("./prog","prog",NULL);
}
```

All works fine, but why does `execl` just run before `printf`? Could someone help me?

Comment: Try `printf ("abc"); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: OT: It should be `execl(..., (char*) NULL);`.

Comment: Line buffering: the output from `printf()` is not forced out unless you turn on no-buffering (add a newline and it would usually appear; pipe the output of the program and even a newline won't help, but `fflush()` will).  The functions in the [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) family of functions do _not_  flush the standard I/O buffers of the invoking program.

Comment: The question [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork) covers most of the ground you need to know about in a slightly different context.

Answer (score 6):

The `printf` actually does run first, however it's output is buffered.

You can flush the buffer either by adding a newline (`\n`) to the end of the string or by calling `fflush(stdout)`:

```
 printf("abc\n");
```

Or:

```
printf("abc");
fflush(stdout);
```