# write() Output Missing

Tags: c, terminal, output

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //variables
  int status, fout, waitcall;
  pid_t pid, ppid, cpid;

  pid = getpid();

  //write to terminal
  write(fout, "Hello World - I am parent:  ",29);
  write(1, (void*)&pid, sizeof(pid));
  write(1, "  !!\n\n", 7);

  int returnchild = fork();

  // fork failed; exit
  if ( returnchild < 0 ) {
    //fail code
  }

  // child (new process)
  else if ( returnchild == 0 ) {
    //getpid(), waitpid() then write;

    if ( waitcall == -1 ) {
        perror("waitpid\n\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if
}

// parent goes down this path
else {
   //some code here    
}
return 0;
} // end main
```

> I want output to the terminal so I can understand where the program is.  Does not output to terminal?  Was working with printf but want to use system call.

Comment: You'll need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  That'll include information about how the command is run.

Comment: How is `fout` defined? And why are you using `write` to write to the terminal? What's the value of `pid`? It's likely not a valid ASCII string, so writing it's value to the terminal isn't going to do what you think. It needs to be converted to a string. You might also want to look up `strlen`.

Comment: Note that the last `write()` prints a null byte to the terminal.  The middle `write()` prints 4 or 8 bytes of binary data; that is not going to be readable.  The first `write()` also prints a null byte to the terminal.  When using the low-level I/O functions like `read()` and `write()`, you have to do the formatting, or use the POSIX function [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) to do the formatting to a file descriptor (as opposed to a file stream like `fprintf()` et al).

Comment: `fout` is uninitialized.

Comment: Note that the `waitpid()` call in the child (`else if (returnchild == 0)`) will always fail as the child process has no children of its own.  The parent can wait for the child; the child won't successfully wait for anything unless the code also creates child processes (uses `fork()`), which you don't show.

Comment: "*... but want to use system call*" -- Why?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with the code, including that what you provide is not really an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Here is revised code, closely based on your code, with some of the flaws in your code still present but others fixed.  Some extra instrumentation is added.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int status, waitcall;
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    // write to terminal
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello World - I am parent:  ", 29);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, (void *) & pid, sizeof(pid));
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "  !!\n\n", 7);

    int returnchild = fork();

    if (returnchild < 0)
    {
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (returnchild == 0)
    {
        // child (new process)
        printf("Child of %d (%d) at play: %d\n", (int)pid, (int)getppid(), (int)getpid());
        waitcall = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        if (waitcall == -1)
        {
            perror("child - waitpid() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Wait return PID %d (status 0x%.4X)\n", waitcall, status);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        // parent goes down this path
        printf("Parent %d created child %d\n", (int)getpid(), returnchild);
        while ((waitcall = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) != -1)
            printf("Parent waited for %d (status 0x%.4X)\n", waitcall, status);
        printf("Parent: all done\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

Program was called `wst13`, and its output was run through a program `vis` that makes non-printing characters visible.

```
$ wst13 | vis
child - waitpid() failed: No child processes
Hello World - I am parent:  \000\035@\000\000  !!

\000Child of 16413 (16413) at play: 16415
Parent 16413 created child 16415
Parent waited for 16415 (status 0x0100)
Parent: all done
$
```

#### What changed?

The variable [`fout` was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134842/write-output-missing#comment63755951_38134842) as [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) noted, so it wasn't safe to use in the first `write()` call.  I replaced it with the 'official' POSIX name for the standard output file descriptor, `STDOUT_FILENO`, though it is tempting to use `1` instead.  The variables `ppid` and `cpid` were not used so they were removed too.

The action for the `else if (returnchild == 0)` was written.  It reports some PID values, then calls `waitpid()` because your comments said it did — and the `waitpid()` fails because the child has not created any of its own children.

The action for the `else` (parent) process was written.  It reports some PID values, then calls `waitpid()` in a loop, reporting the PID and status of any dead child, and exiting the loop when there are no more children to wait for.  It then reports when it is all done.

One of the problems [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134842/write-output-missing#comment63700895_38134842) was that the first and third `write()` operations write trailing nulls because the lengths are one too long, and hence include the terminal null.  You can see these in the output: they are reported as `\000` by the `vis` program.  Also the middle `write()` prints the 4 bytes of the `pid` as raw data, leading to the byte sequence `\035@\000\000`.  When treated as the bytes of a little-endian integer, that amounts to 256 * 64 + 29 = 16413, which is the value recorded in `pid`.

The sequencing of the outputs is indeterminate on a multi-core machine (Intel Core i7 inside a MacBook Pro, in this case).  However, the child's error is reported before any of the standard output is reported by `vis` (see [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663).  Without the use of `| vis`, sample output looks like:

```
$ wst13
Hello World - I am parent:  %@  !!

Parent 16421 created child 16422
Child of 16421 (16421) at play: 16422
child - waitpid() failed: No child processes
Parent waited for 16422 (status 0x0100)
Parent: all done
$
```

#### What's still a problem?

I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134842/write-output-missing/38165738#comment63700895_38134842):

> Note that the last `write()` prints a null byte to the terminal. The middle `write()` prints 4 or 8 bytes of binary data; that is not going to be readable. The first `write()` also prints a null byte to the terminal. When using the low-level I/O functions like `read()` and `write()`, you have to do the formatting, or use the POSIX function [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) to do the formatting to a file descriptor (as opposed to a file stream like `fprintf()` et al).

One of the many ways of fixing that would be:

```
    // write to terminal
    const char hw[] = "Hello World - I am parent:  ";
    const char nn[] = "  !!\n\n";
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, hw, sizeof(hw) - 1) != sizeof(hw) - 1 ||
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, (void *) & pid, sizeof(pid)) != sizeof(pid) ||
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, nn, sizeof(nn) - 1) != sizeof(nn) - 1)
    {
        perror("short write to standard output");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

That still prints gibberish for the PID.  Another option is:

```
    // write to terminal
    const char hw[] = "Hello World - I am parent:  ";
    const char nn[] = "  !!\n\n";
    dprintf(STDOUT_FILENO, "%s%d%s", hw, (int)pid, nn);
```

There are a multitude of other ways to get the same output from that.  And you can fix the middle call to `write()`:

```
    // write to terminal
    const char hw[] = "Hello World - I am parent:  ";
    const char nn[] = "  !!\n\n";
    char pidstr[16];
    snprintf(pidstr, sizeof(pidstr), "%d", (int)pid);
    int pidlen = strlen(pidstr);
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, hw, sizeof(hw) - 1) != sizeof(hw) - 1 ||
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, pidstr, pidlen) != pidlen ||
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, nn, sizeof(nn) - 1) != sizeof(nn) - 1)
    {
        perror("short write to standard output");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

And so the possible remedies continue.  How many more ways can you find to do it?