# Fork failing in C

Tags: c, fork, pid

I'm having a problem with fork running in a function I'm using to create a terminal for a school project.

This function is called to handle the user input when they type in a command:

```
void handleExternalCommands(char ** arr)
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    printf("pid is ", (long) pid);

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        int status = execvp(arr[0], arr);

        printf("im in the child process");

        if (status == -1)
        {
            // error handle
        }

    }

    wait();
}
```

However, no matter what I type in, I can't actually make it inside of the if statement. If I try to find out what's going on with pid by using:

```
printf(pid);
```

I get a segmentation fault error?

Thanks for your help in advance, everyone.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed the code to what it is above. Printing the pid only happens once and it prints nothing: "pid is "

Comment: If fork is failing, you can easily determine why.  `if( pid == -1 ) perror("fork");`

Comment: `printf(pid)` does not print `pid`, unless `pid` is a string without formatting characters.   Read the documentation for `printf()`.

Comment: If the `execvp()` works, the `printf()` is never executed.  You'd only see the message from `printf()` if (a) you added a newline to the end and (b) the `execvp()` failed.  (OK: you might see it eventually even without a newline, but the newline is a good idea.)  Move the `printf()` to before the `execvp()` and (definitely) add the newline and you should see the information.

Comment: It's because that's not how you use `printf()`...

Comment: I've amended the code to what it is above. printing the pid reads, "pid is ". And it only prints it once. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `execvp()` works, the `printf()` is never executed.  You'd only see the message from `printf()` if (a) you added a newline to the end and (b) the `execvp()` failed.  (OK: you might see it eventually even without a newline, but the newline is a good idea.)

Move the `printf()` to before the `execvp()` and (definitely) add the newline and you should see the information.  See also [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork), but note you are running into a different consequence of not terminating `printf()` output with newlines.

As to `printf(pid)` crashing, you need to read the manual on [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
and add compiler options so you get told about erroneous use.

You probably need:

```
printf("PID %d\n", pid);
```

That assumes that `pid_t` is sufficiently compatible with `int` not to run into trouble — a moderately safe assumption, but one which can be avoided by writing:

```
printf("PID %d\n", (int)pid);
```

(or use `int pid;` as the definition).  But the key point is that you need to use `printf()` correctly, and `execvp()` does not return unless it fails.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for such a concise answer. I think I realize my mistakes now, and my problems are specific to the implementation of my program and not because fork is failing.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Although `fork()` can fail, it is relatively rare.  Generally, assume the problem is in your own code, not in the system — you'll be correct far more often than you'll be wrong.  (Even if `fork()` fails, most often it is because of a problem in your program, not a system failure.)