# Prevent program from forking

Tags: python, unix, process, fork, limit

I want to run a binary in Python, but I want to disallow the binary from making new processes. It seems like the standard way to do this is to call `setrlimit` through the `resource` module, and constrain `resource.RLIMIT_NPROC`. However, my attempts have all failed.

Here's a simple example:

foo.py:

```py
import subprocess
import resource
import os

def set_nproc() -> None: 
    resource.setrlimit(
        resource.RLIMIT_NPROC,
        (1, 1),
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], preexec_fn=set_nproc)
```

foo.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("Running C Program!\n");
    int pid = fork();
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, `a.out` is the binary produced by compiling `foo.c`. Running `foo.py`, I'd expect the following to take place:

1. `subprocess.Popen` will spawn a new process. Before running `./a.out`, it will run the `set_nproc` function, which will set the `RLIMIT_NPROC` soft and hard limit to `1`.
2. The new process will run the binary `a.out`. The binary will print `Running C Program!` and terminate because the next line tries to spawn a new process, which is not allowed.

It seems like my understanding is not correct because the C program actually terminates to completion (i.e., I do not receive any sort of error). How can I fix this?

Note: I realize that `setrlimit` imposes a limit on the *user* and not the *process*. Even then, I'd expect an error to take place somewhere here.

Comment: Your code worked, though you wouldn't know because you never checked for the assigned `pid` and verified that it isn't the failure value `-1`.  Try adding a `printf("this is pid %d\n", pid);` after `fork()`, compile and run it, and then compare with adjustment the rlimit value in the Python code from what you had to a much higher number (greater than the total process that exists for the user running that program for the entire system). [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866250/fork-failing-in-c) (this question may be considered a duplicate of that in essence).

Comment: (also you need to `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `stdlib` for `printf`, but this isn't an important detail for the question at hand, but is important if you want the C program to be more correct; the other thing is to use the `pid_t` instead of `int` to capture the `pid` value, and then `%ld` for the token as per [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533606/what-is-the-correct-printf-specifier-for-printing-pid-t) to ensure most correctness.)

Comment: Essentially, many things in C's standard library will run and return something and won't crash the program, unless you try to use that return value inappropriately, and then it may crash with a segmentation fault.