# Fork never enters child's process

Tags: c, shell, process, operating-system, fork

I'm writing a code that mimics a shell behavior, specifically & and |.

My function receives user commands, and checks if there's an & at the end, then the child process should run in the background and the parent should not wait for it to finish and continue executing commands.

Also it's supposed to check if there's a | in the input array and run two child processes while piping their stdin and stdout.

I have implemented the behavior for &, but whenever I compile and run my code, I only get the printf sentence from the parent's process.

I would like to hear ideas how to fix this, in addition I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the implementation of | (pipes) and how to prevent zombies.

```
int process_arglist(int count, char** arglist) {
int pid = fork();
printf("%d", pid);
switch (pid) {
case -1:
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fork failed\n");
    return 1;
    break;

case 0: // Son's proccess
    printf("I got to son");
    //check last arglist argument
    if (strcmp(arglist[count - 1], "&") == 0) {
        setpgid(0, 0);
        arglist[count - 1] = NULL;
        if (execvp(*arglist, arglist) < 0) {     //execute the command
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: execvp failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else { //There's no & at the end, look for pipes
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count) {
            if (strcmp(arglist[i], "|") == 0) {
                int pid2 = fork();
                if (pid2 < 0) {
                    //fork failed, handle error
                }
                if (pid2 == 0) { // Son's proccess

                } else { //Parent's code

                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;
    //in case no & and no |, call execvp

default: //Parent's code
    printf("I go to parent");
    return 1;
    break;
}
return 0;
```

}

The output is always "I go to parent"

Comment: Print debug output to `stderr`, as it's not buffered. Else put a `\n` at the end of every statement to print, or flush the stream by calling  `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: Do not ask two questions in one post. Make the second a separate one.

Comment: @Yunnosch The ouput is "I go to parent"

Comment: Unlikely. That does not include the number I expect from `printf("%d", pid);`.

Comment: Maybe output gets more helpful with a few `\n`. (i.e. I agree with alk)

Comment: "*how to prevent zombies.*" [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for the children to end.

Comment: Closely related to [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork/).

Comment: @Yunnosch I have made the suggested changes, now it goes to both parent and son, but ls& is not working

Comment: Note that in English, it is conventional to use the gender-neutral term 'child' rather than 'son' for processes; and grandchild, parent, grandparent and sibling.

Comment: Now that the false impression is clarified that the code never ends up in child, please split the next part of your multi-question into a new separate question. Asking about the other problems under your current title is not helpful. (Do not edit this question to ask for something else than initially.)

Comment: SO is not a *do-my-homework* service.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you are right about "child" vs "son" process in English. However, in some languages (notably French) it is customary to speak of "masculine" process (in French, you'll find "processus fils" but never "processus enfant", where "fils" is son, and "enfant" is child). Perhaps OP is natively French!

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back you last change though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your code is for Linux or some other POSIX system. Read some good book on Linux programming (perhaps the old [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf), freely downloadable, or something newer).

**[stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered**, and `stdout` and `printf` is often (but not always) line-buffered. Buffering happens for efficiency reasons (calling [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) very often, e.g. once per output byte, is *very* slow; you should prefer doing `write`-s on chunks of several kilobytes).

BTW you'll better handle failure of [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (see [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) by using [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) thru [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (or [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) on `errno`). You (and the user of your shell) needs to be informed of the failure reason (and your current code don't show it).

I recommend to often end your `printf` format control strings with `\n` (this works when stdout is line-buffered) or to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places.

As a rule of thumb, I suggest doing `fflush(NULL);`  before every call to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

The behavior you observe is consistent with the hypothesis that some `printf`-ed data is staying in buffers (e.g. of `stdout`).

You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program (or on other ones, e.g. some existing shell process) to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are done.

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), improve your code to get no warnings, and [use the debugger `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (with care, it can be used on forking processes).

> I'm writing a code that mimics a shell behavior

You probably are coding some shell. Then *study* for inspiration the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shells (most -probably all- Linux shells are free software).

> I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the implementation of | (pipes) and how to prevent zombies.

Explaining all that requires a lot of space (several chapters of a book, or perhaps, an entire book) and *don't fit here* or on any other forum. So **read a good Linux** or POSIX **programming book**. Regarding pipes, read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (it should be created with [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) *before* the `fork`). Regarding avoiding [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), you need to carefully call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or some similar call.

Comment: I have removed the printf, and updated my code, still & is not working.

Comment: So, continue to work on your shell. We won't do your homework. I gave enough hints.