# Creation of child processes in C

Tags: c, linux

would it be possible to help me with creation of short program in which parent process produces 1 child process, the child produces the next child, the subsequent child produces the next child, etc. .... so that all children are in total 16. How can I using the pstree command, present the tree of these processes ? Till now I was able to write something like, but I’ not sure if its correct:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid != 0)
        {
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you ran `pstree`, what happened?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but mind that `fork` returns `-1` on error, this isn't critical in your program, but a good habit to check.

Comment: The first thing to do is add appropriate diagnostic printing, which will include the PID and probably PPID (functions `getpid()` and `getppid()`).  Upgrade the `waitpid()` call: `int status; int corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);` and print `corpse` (the PID of the process that died) and its status (`printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);` or thereabouts).  Consider whether the `return 0;` inside the `if` should be `break;`, or whether you should have a `sleep(1);` there (5 is probably too big).

Comment: actually, should be enough to replace `sleep(5)` with `system("pstree -lhp")` or somesuch

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912112/creation-of-child-processes-in-c#comment98479129_55912112), add diagnostic printing to help you understand what's going on.  Key values are the loop control, `i`, the PID and PPID of the process, and the value in the `pid` variable.  You also want to instrument the `waitpid()` call.

That leads to code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        printf("%d: (PPID = %d) - post fork %d: pid = %d\n",
               (int)getpid(), (int)getppid(), i, (int)pid);
        fflush(0);
        if (pid != 0)
        {
            int status;
            int corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            printf("%d: (PPID = %d) child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                   (int)getpid(), (int)getppid(), corpse, status);
            fflush(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d: (PPID = %d) sleeping\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    fflush(0);
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The `fflush()` calls aren't necessary if you run the output to a terminal.  If you run the output through a pipe (like I did when generating the output below), they become crucial.  See also [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/).  If you replaced the `return 0;` in the `if` with `return i;`, you'd also get some interesting information.

Running that program leads to output similar to this:

```
74830: (PPID = 72799) - post fork 0: pid = 74833
74833: (PPID = 74830) - post fork 0: pid = 0
74833: (PPID = 74830) - post fork 1: pid = 74834
74834: (PPID = 74833) - post fork 1: pid = 0
74834: (PPID = 74833) - post fork 2: pid = 74835
74835: (PPID = 74834) - post fork 2: pid = 0
74835: (PPID = 74834) - post fork 3: pid = 74836
74836: (PPID = 74835) - post fork 3: pid = 0
74836: (PPID = 74835) - post fork 4: pid = 74837
74837: (PPID = 74836) - post fork 4: pid = 0
74837: (PPID = 74836) - post fork 5: pid = 74838
74838: (PPID = 74837) - post fork 5: pid = 0
74838: (PPID = 74837) - post fork 6: pid = 74839
74839: (PPID = 74838) - post fork 6: pid = 0
74839: (PPID = 74838) - post fork 7: pid = 74840
74840: (PPID = 74839) - post fork 7: pid = 0
74840: (PPID = 74839) - post fork 8: pid = 74841
74841: (PPID = 74840) - post fork 8: pid = 0
74841: (PPID = 74840) - post fork 9: pid = 74842
74842: (PPID = 74841) - post fork 9: pid = 0
74842: (PPID = 74841) - post fork 10: pid = 74843
74843: (PPID = 74842) - post fork 10: pid = 0
74843: (PPID = 74842) - post fork 11: pid = 74844
74844: (PPID = 74843) - post fork 11: pid = 0
74844: (PPID = 74843) - post fork 12: pid = 74845
74845: (PPID = 74844) - post fork 12: pid = 0
74845: (PPID = 74844) - post fork 13: pid = 74846
74846: (PPID = 74845) - post fork 13: pid = 0
74846: (PPID = 74845) - post fork 14: pid = 74847
74847: (PPID = 74846) - post fork 14: pid = 0
74847: (PPID = 74846) - post fork 15: pid = 74848
74848: (PPID = 74847) - post fork 15: pid = 0
74848: (PPID = 74847) sleeping
74847: (PPID = 74846) child 74848 exited with status 0x0000
74846: (PPID = 74845) child 74847 exited with status 0x0000
74845: (PPID = 74844) child 74846 exited with status 0x0000
74844: (PPID = 74843) child 74845 exited with status 0x0000
74843: (PPID = 74842) child 74844 exited with status 0x0000
74842: (PPID = 74841) child 74843 exited with status 0x0000
74841: (PPID = 74840) child 74842 exited with status 0x0000
74840: (PPID = 74839) child 74841 exited with status 0x0000
74839: (PPID = 74838) child 74840 exited with status 0x0000
74838: (PPID = 74837) child 74839 exited with status 0x0000
74837: (PPID = 74836) child 74838 exited with status 0x0000
74836: (PPID = 74835) child 74837 exited with status 0x0000
74835: (PPID = 74834) child 74836 exited with status 0x0000
74834: (PPID = 74833) child 74835 exited with status 0x0000
74833: (PPID = 74830) child 74834 exited with status 0x0000
74830: (PPID = 72799) child 74833 exited with status 0x0000
```

If you were feeling even more fussy, you could add timing to the printing operations — you'd probably need to report at the microsecond level to see much difference.