# After fork() not getting expected output.Why?

Tags: c, fork, fork-join

I have a C program that forks, which I'm running from a linux bash shell.

Problem:-After forking Not geetting expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
void main(){
    pid_t p1;
    int size;
    char *new;
    char test[2]={'\0'};
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("\nIn Parent process");
    printf("\nElements of Array are:");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) { 
         printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    p1=fork();
    if(!p1) {
        printf("\nIn child Process");
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

actual result

```
In Parent process
Elements of Array are:12345
In child ProcessElements of Array are:12345
```

desired output:-

```
In Parent process
Elements of Array are:12345
In child Process
```

Comment: Make sure you end your printing operations with a newline, rather than (or as well as) starting them with a newline.  That helps unless you're sending output to a pipe or file instead of a terminal.  If you're worried about that, then make sure you use `fflush()` liberally (but note that it slows things down — not too liberally).

Answer (score 2):

I found your problem in [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530870/4851565). Basically, your output from the `printf()` method is getting buffered and that buffer is being used by the child process. If you call `fflush(0)` before you fork, your IO buffer should get flushed properly and you should get the desired output. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just flag a closure as a duplicate