# C - How to implement code that will only be executed once in parent process since fork() is called?

Tags: c, shell, process, fork, pid

I'm trying to execute `printf(">>");` only once in the parent process. Meaning that once I call fork() and a child process is born, the program (once it starts executing code from the top again), should skip `printf(">>");`

Note: I'm trying to implement something very similar to the Python Shell. Notice how when you enter `print("example")` in the Python Shell, it print "example" and not ">>>example"

I apologize for the low readability, I really tried my best.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

char * selected = malloc(256);
char line[255];
pid_t pid = getpid();

while (1){

    printf("(In parent) PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    // if (ps is parent && line is NOT executed later on by fork){
    printf(">>");
    //}

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; // removes \n 

    if (strcmp(line, "fork") == 0){
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            printf("(In child) PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (pid != 0)` ? `fork()` returns `0` if you are in the child, so... use that information.

Comment: if you want to only do `printf("(In child) PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());` in the child just do `exit(0);` or `return 0;` after, and `wait(NULL);` in else branch

Comment: anyway your question is unclear, do you want to also loop and `fgets` in child ? do you want child has child too etc ?

Comment: @KamilCuk doesn't work for when used before pid = fork()

Comment: @bruno no need for multiple child ps's

Comment: @mumcuhkm34 so what the alone child has to do except `printf("(In child) PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());` ?

Comment: @bruno nothing for now, will implement execlp() once i get this to work. But for now just want to have it print PID & PPID without the programming printing ">>" right before it.

Comment: @mumcuhkm34 to say what you do not want does not help to know what you want. What the child process must do ? also why the `while` if "*I'm trying to execute printf(">>"); **only once** in the parent process*" ?

Comment: @bruno just trying to give an idea of what I want to achieve. The only once part means don't execute that line after fork is called.

Comment: sorry but "an idea of" is not a specification, please edit your question when you will know, currently it is not possible to help you

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; // removes \n`  *No*, it doesn't "remove \n".  It removes the last character read, which doesn't have to be `'\n'`. If `fgets()` returns a zero-length string, you invoke undefined behavior because `strlen(line)` is zero and `strlen(line) - 1` falls outside the bounds of the array. And if `fgets()` fails the contents of `line` could be indeterminate, which means you've just invoked undefined behavior. Return values for I/O calls such as `fgets()` must be checked for failure. If `fgets()` works, `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = 0;` will properly remove the `'\n'`.

Comment: @mumcuhkm34 : Why are you tagging this _shell_? Your question does not involve a shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printf anomaly after "fork()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica well found. Unfortunately I cannot vote your duplicate after I retracted an other close reason until the question is edited

Answer (score 1):

Just call `printf(">>");` followed by `fflush(NULL);`  (read [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)) before your  `fork()`.

Remember that [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered. See [setvbuf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Consider also studying, for inspiration, the source code of small shells such as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell).