# fork() - Child code is called multiple times (same PID)

Tags: c

As an excersise, I wrote a C program that handles Signals and counts them etc. The program itself is actually "working" as intended, however:

The program uses fork() several times, creating a single child first, which in turn then forks two more children (i.e. grandchildren of the top-level parent). The top-level parent waits for the child to finish, and before that, the child waits for its children to finish.

Trying to understand what's going on I printed a little debug message everytime the child code executes (to make sure its only executing once - as intended).

This is what I get though:

```
Note: Child PID: 28411
Note: Grandchild 2 PID: 28413
Note: Child PID: 28411
Note: Grandchild 1 PID: 28412
Note: Child PID: 28411

Grandchild with PID 28413 called SIGUSR2 1139226 times
Grandchild with PID 28412 called SIGUSR1 1140378 times

Print to console successful
All done!
[Done] exited with code=0 in 5.493 seconds
```

The first child call is correct, the grandchildren are fine as well. However, the child code, **for some reason**, is executed two more times. Its also not a new process, since the PID is the same.

This is how I fork the child:

```c
pid_t child = fork();

    if (child == -1) {
        perror("Failure to fork in main\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (child == 0) {
        childCode();
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
```

And this is how I fork the grandchildren:

```c
pid_t grandchild1 = fork();

    if (grandchild1 == -1) {
        // Error
        perror("Failure to fork first grandchild");
    }
    else if (grandchild1 == 0) 
        // Grandchild
        grandchildCode(1); 
    else {
        // Child 
        pid_t grandchild2 = fork();

        if (grandchild2 == -1) {
            // Error
            perror("Failure to fork second grandchild");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (grandchild2 == 0) {
            // Grandchild 
            grandchildCode(2);
        }
        else {
            // Child
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
```

Because I dont want to clutter this thread with useless code, here is the full program on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XnZEaaNZ *(or should I include it here?)*

I would be very thankful for any information on this. I can't figure it out.

Comment: At least include the code that prints out the pids in your question. (I bet it's an issue with not flushing a buffer before forking, though)

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `*printf`s.

Comment: @anastaciu YES! That's it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @sutterseba and Shawn too ;)

Comment: It's almost certainly related to [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530663/15168).  Probably a duplicate — but the code isn't complete enough for that to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output suggests the flow is working exactly as you expect, the problem seems to be with the output itself, `stdout` is not being flushed in time before the next fork is called and will be passed to the children which will then print the text, as expected since it's in their `stdout`.

This can be resolved if you place a `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` calls.