# Different output when redirecting to a file

Tags: c, linux, bash, redirect, fork

I have this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        fork();
        printf("hello\n");
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

When i run this code in the terminal, i'll get 10 lines of "hello".

But after redirecting the output to a file:
`./test > file.txt`
I'm getting 12 lines of "hello" in the file.

Why this difference ?

Comment: The difference is because the standard output is (by default) line buffered when connected to an interactive device, but fully buffered otherwise, such as when connected to a file.  Adding an `fflush(stdiin);` after each `printf()` should help.

Comment: Related: [printf anomaly after "fork()"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530663/24022720).

Comment: Basically, the parent process writes a `"hello\n"` to `stdout`, then cycles around the loop and forks.  If `stdout` is in line-buffered mode then that output is written to the terminal immediately because of the trailing newline.  But if it is in fully-buffered mode then that text is still in the buffer when the parent forks, so the child gets its own copy of it along with the rest of the process state.

Answer (score 0):

Because you *just* do `fork` but don't check the return value (for 0 to execute child code), you're forking *more* children than you think.

The parent also does the `printf` and *not* just the child.

And, after the first loop, the *first* child *also* does a `fork` so you have an unexpected grandchild.

It also acts like parent and child and both do a print.

So, you get *six* total prints from the loop.

And, because there is *no* `exit` call in the children, they "fall through" and execute the parent code at the bottom.

So, you get *four* prints from the code *after* the loop.

And, you should *loop* on `wait` because you `fork` *two* children but only do a *single* `wait`.

---

Adding some `getpid` and `getppid` calls can show what is really happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PRINT(_fmt) \
    printf("%d/%d " _fmt,getpid(),getppid())

int
main(void)
{
    int f;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fork();
        PRINT("hello\n");
    }

    wait(NULL);
    PRINT("world\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
242293/2809616 hello
242293/2809616 hello
242294/242293 hello
242294/242293 hello
242295/242293 hello
242295/242293 world
242296/242294 hello
242296/242294 world
242293/2809616 world
242294/2806078 world
```

---

Here is the corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PRINT(_fmt) \
    printf("%d/%d " _fmt,getpid(),getppid())

int
main(void)
{
    int f;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            PRINT("hello\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
    PRINT("world\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
242316/242314 hello
242315/242314 hello
242314/2809616 world
```

Comment: The question is about why the OP observes a different number of lines of output when stdout is connected to a terminal than they do when it is redirected to a file.  I think you have answered a completely different question.