# Weird GCC behaviour with fork and printf with and without newline character

Tags: c, gcc

**gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)**

Also tested on few online compilers (I know they may not be a reliable option)

### Tests (Compare Example 1 and Example 2)

Example 1

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("before-fork\n");
    int a;
    fork();
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT 1

```
before-fork
0x7fff58cd3324
0x7fff58cd3324
```

Example 2 (only replaced '\n' with a space in `printf("before-fork\n")`)

OUTPUT 2

```
before-fork 0x7ffce0196bb4
before-fork 0x7ffce0196bb4
```

### Expected Behavior

OUTPUT 1

Is this a bug? if not then what is the reason for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Pipe the output of the first program to `cat` and observe the result.  When the output device is not a terminal, the standard I/O library makes the output fully buffered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

No.

> if not then what is the reason for that?

`stdout` output is (by default in this case) *line* buffered in process local memory. The content of the buffer is flushed on newline.