# Flow of Fork() system call

Tags: c, operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    printf("hello\n");
    fork();
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

if fork() system call creates a child which starts its execution from the next instruction doesn't it mean the output should have 2 "hello" statements?

doesn't it mean the 2nd and 3rd fork calls are basically useless?

the output that i am getting is printing 8 "hello" statements.

my concepts might be wrong. Please explain.

Comment: This could conceivably print extra messages if the output buffer is not flushed before the extra `fork()` calls. In that case, the output buffer will be duplicated, and flushed when the program exits.

Comment: Note the answers to the question [`printf()` anomaly after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530663/15168).  Yes, the second and third fork calls are useless while the output is line buffered; they affect the number of lines printed when the output is fully buffered.  If you pipe the output of the program through `cat` (for example — other programs would work roughly the same), you will get 8 lines of output.

Answer (score -1):

This should print hello twice. I just run this and I only see two print statements.

Double check you are compiling and running the right file. Maybe try removing all compiled files including `.o` files and compile and run again.